# Как заменить php функцию проверки зарегистрированного пользователя на jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, аутентификация

Всем привет! Подскажите, как заменить php функцию проверки зарегистрированного пользователя на jquery?

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()){
echo "Welcome, registered user!";
}
else {
echo "Welcome, visitor!";
};
?>
```

Comment: Вы действительно хотите отдать проверку подлинности юзера самому юзеру?

Comment: @Visman не понял вас - что имеете ввиду?

Comment: js исполняется на стороне клиента, т.е он уязвимый.

Answer (score 2):

Просто заменить не получится. Как вариант, можно написать функцию на JavaScript(jQuery), которая будет отправлять запрос php-скрипту для проведения аутентификации пользователя, и в зависимости от ответа выполнять определенные действия.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос странный конечно, но если подумать в этом направлении немного, то авторизация это по сути определение что пользователь зашедший однажды на сайт, а потом посетивший его снова является именно тем самым пользователем. Например можно генерировать какой то токен и хранить его в куки.  Главное чтобы куки не унесли, ну или каким то образом собирать инфу уникальную для этого компьютера, потом на основе ее делать токен, тогда пользователь будет привязан к конкретной машине. 
Тут возможно что то подчеркнуть https://xakep.ru/2015/01/30/user-web-tracking-howto/

Answer (score 0):

```
var is = '<?php echo is_user_logged_in() ? 1 : 0; ?>';
if(is == '1') alert('Welcome, registered user!');
else alert('Welcome, visitor!');
```

Comment: А почему минусуете-то? Ответ соответствует вопросу. Проверка сделана на стороне клиента, на чистом javascript :)

Comment: @Visman не знаю кто минусовал, но видимо потому, что при такой записи браузер клиента только с визитером здоровается и ему плевать залогинен ты или нет..)

Answer (score -2):

Как вариант, можно использовать `ajax` запрос в базу данных, если такой пользователь есть в базе, тогда эти данные вставитьи в `if else`.

Comment: Вы сказали то же самое, что и @NikitaRomannikov.

Comment: Извиняюсь я просто до конца не прочитал ответ, там шла речь про какую-то функцию и я дальше не читал.

Comment: Ставлю минус, за неумение читать ответы коллег.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev надо читать коментарий, там я извинился за невнимательность.